# import another python class file to the main file in jupyter notebook on mac

Tags: python, class, import, jupyter-notebook

I have a python project

|main.py
|app_class.py
|...

I want to run this project in jupyter notebook
I have changed all files to .ipynb file

there is a problem that I don't know it
when I run the main file the app will be stopped because of the error below

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-52894e9ef8a0> in <module>
----> 1 from app_class import *
      2 
      3 if __name__ == '__main__':
      4     app = App()
      5     app.run()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_class'
```

My main file content is

```
from app_class import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Is `app_class` in the same directory where you are running this code from?

Comment: yes it is in the same dir